# Setting up a raspberry pi as a gateway firewall for security purposes?

Tags: wifi, server, security, raspberry-pi-os-buster

so I have a Minetest server and I want to deploy it on the internet through my raspberry pi, so de RBPI acts as a firewall and IDS and all the traffic goes through it.

The Minetest server is on my laptop and my question is if the solution is connecting my laptop to the raspberry as it was a router, where it gonna be set up the firewall, and how to do that in a simple approach (using wired ethernet, wifi ap, ssh...).

Comment: Have you looked at setting up Pi-Hole using the Firewall Configurations?

Comment: But as I'm reading, Pi-Hole is more useful for web purpouses right? a DNS sinkhole. I don't know if it fits with the idea of a protection and monitoring system for my game server.

Comment: What operating system, what version do you use?

Comment: I'm using raspbian and ubuntu 20.04 for the game server

Answer (score 2):

On the Raspberry Pi OS you have its firewall **nftables** available. It is the successor of **iptables** and replaces the old popular iptables, ip6tables, arptables and ebtables. So I suggest to use nftables because it is the future and removes some limits of the old firewall. Install it with

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install nftables
```

and have a look at its usage with `man nft`. It is very powerful and should be able to cover all of your use cases. Of course you can still use the old `iptables` out of the box as long as it will not become deprecated.

Comment: I'll check, and any recommendations about IDS? thank you for your answer!

Comment: @raldu Haven't used an Intrusion Detection System until now, so cannot say much about it.